# Parsing json value from string

Tags: c#, json

I need to get value for error under results In the following json which I've got in a JObject :

```
  {
   "multicast_id": 6958024579437543738,
   "success": 0,
   "failure": 1,
   "canonical_ids": 0,
   "results": [
      {
       "error": "NotRegistered"
      }
     ].     
   }
```

I've tried things like

```
 JArray errors = (JArray)o["results"];
 string errorMessage = (string)o["results"].   ["error"];
```

But it cannot get the correct result.

Comment: The "error" map object is the first element of "results" array.
I think you mistake the "results" array as a map.

Comment: Thanks All. Helped me fix the problem! I was pretty close I see.... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var errors = o["results"][0];
string errorMessage = (string)errors["error"];
```

That should give you the "NotRegistered" string.